# Using input type="range" to scale an image

Tags: javascript, html, image, input, scale

What the title says. Is it possible? I want an image to scale up and down from it's center using a slider such as the input type="range".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share the code what you've already tried...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<input id="ranger" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="100" />
<hr />
<img id="image" src="http://google.com/images/logo.png" width="275" height="95" />

var ranger = document.getElementById('ranger'),
    image =  document.getElementById('image'),
    width = image.width,
    height = image.height;

ranger.onchange = function(){
    image.width = width * (ranger.value / 100);
    image.height = height * (ranger.value / 100);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DnE83/1/

Study it, work out how it works.

Comment: THank you very much, this was precisely what I needed! I couldn't figure out the value/100 thing but I get it now. THank you!

Comment: One more thing though, do you know how to make the image scale towards its center instead of towards its upper left?

Comment: you need to wrap the image in a div then align it in the center

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DnE83/3/ - if you need any further help, you should open another question.