# Making an image scale towards its center

Tags: javascript, html, image, scale, center

I recently posted a question regarding how to scale an image using the input type="range" element. I recieved an excellent answer from user [Prisoner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/475125/prisoner):

```
<input id="ranger" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="100" />
<hr />
<img id="image" src="http://google.com/images/logo.png" width="275" height="95" />

var ranger = document.getElementById('ranger'),
image =  document.getElementById('image'),
width = image.width,
height = image.height;

ranger.onchange = function(){
image.width = width * (ranger.value / 100);
image.height = height * (ranger.value / 100);
}
```

HOWEVER! This scales the image towards its upper left corner and I need an image that scales towards its center. How do I achieve this? Can't seem to get it to work using text-align:center or anything...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would not work with a regular `<img />`, I'd rather use a div with a background

Comment: This additional question fits quite well into your original question: [Using input type="range" to scale an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634036/using-input-type-range-to-scale-an-image)

Comment: Replaced the img tag with a div and background, now it doesn't scale...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Assuming your images start out at full width, you just need to take into account the image center, then reposition the image on size change.

add to css:
   `img{    position: relative;    }`

and amend your function like so:

```
ranger.onchange = function(){
image.width = width * (ranger.value / 100);
image.height = height * (ranger.value / 100);

image.style.left=(width/2-image.width/2+"px");
image.style.top=(height/2-image.height/2+"px");    
}
```

Here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/avVHn/)

By the way, did you intend to allow scaling the image down until ~ 1pX1px size? What's the point of that?

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I need! And no, I've changed the min of the range slider to 20 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use align option of img tag.

```
 <img id="image" src="http://google.com/images/logo.png"  align="middle" width="275" height="95" />
```

Comment: The align element is old and deprecated in HTML 4.01 and newer. Doesn't work anymore.